# Flutter and HTML character codes

Tags: flutter

Hi all I am getting data with json from a wordpress website.

My question is this: the title can have some code like `&#8211`.

How can I convert this to show the `"` char?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Should be an easier way but this also works:

Import:

```
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as htmlParser;
```

Line:

```
htmlParser.DocumentFragment.html("&#8211;").text
```

[More info about DocumentFragment](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-html/DocumentFragment-class.html)

On which later you can replace for other characters like the `"` char.

Comment: @OP you should mark this as the answer if it answers your question